# viewpager not detecting onclicklistener

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I am using a viewpager as image slider.

My issue is that onclicklistener is not detecting when the user clicks on the image on each page.

This is my adapter:

```
public class SlidingImage_Adapter extends PagerAdapter {


    private String[] urls;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private Context context;


    public SlidingImage_Adapter(Context context, String[] urls) {
        this.context = context;
        this.urls = urls;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView((View) object);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return urls.length;
    }



    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup view, final int position) {
        final View imageLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.slidingimages_layout, view, false);

        assert imageLayout != null;
        final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) imageLayout
                .findViewById(R.id.image);

        imageLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                //this will log the page number that was click

                Log.d("position","position "+position);//not working
            }
        });


        Glide.with(context)
                .load(urls[position])
                .into(imageView);

        view.addView(imageLayout, 0);

        return imageLayout;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view.equals(object);
    }

    @Override
    public void restoreState(Parcelable state, ClassLoader loader) {
    }

    @Override
    public Parcelable saveState() {
        return null;
    }


}
```

EDIT
Code for the viewPager in recyclerView adapter

```
   holder.mPager.setAdapter(new SlidingImage_Adapter(context,urls));


        holder.indicator.setViewPager(holder.mPager);



//Set circle indicator radius


        NUM_PAGES = urls.length;

        // Auto start of viewpager
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        final Runnable Update = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                if (currentPage == urls.length) {
                    currentPage = 0;
                }
                holder.mPager.setCurrentItem(currentPage++, true);
            }
        };
        Timer swipeTimer = new Timer();
        swipeTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                handler.post(Update);
            }
        }, 3000, 3000);

        // Pager listener over indicator
        holder.indicator.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                currentPage = position;


            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int pos, float arg1, int arg2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int pos) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: write image listener logic inside your fragment which has been added to adapter

Comment: @notTdar, I will include it now as edit

Comment: @notTdar, done, code included

Comment: **Just to understand:** Is the view pager that you are using included in a recyclerview item? Also are the images loading fine?

Comment: @svi.data, yes, and the images are loading fine.

Comment: You didn't mention how the viewpager is being used? Alone or in a recyclerview item?

Comment: @svi.data, it is used inside a recyclerview item

Comment: So you have a set of items that you scroll through vertically, and in each item there is viewpager that slides through images?

Comment: If yes are the list of images the same in each item?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so in your `SlidingImage_Adapter` we will do some changes for your `instantiateItem` method.

Try to change your `instantiateItem` method into this:

```
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup view, final int position) {

//this is the inflater
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

//this is the view
final View imageLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.slidingimages_layout, null);

//this is the imageview in the view 
final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) imageLayout.findViewById(R.id.image);

//use glide to load images into the image views
Glide.with(context)
            .load(urls[position])
            .into(imageView);

//click listener of each image
imageLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            //this will log the page number that was click

            Log.d("position","position "+position); //should work
        }
    });

 //do this now
 ViewPager viewpager = (ViewPager) view;
 viewpager.addView(imageLayout, 0);

 //return the view
 return imageLayout;
}
```

Also change the `isViewFromObject` method to this:

```
@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return view == object;
}
```

Also change the `destroyItem` method to this:

```
@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {

    ViewPager viewpager = (ViewPager) container;
    viewpager.removeView((View) object);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no OnItemClick callback method for ViewPager. If you want to click events on each page then you'll have to build your listener into the page content within your Adapter. Create `Inflater` instance inside `instantiateItem` override method.

something like this:

```
    @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup view, final int position) {
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) view.getContext()
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

final View imageLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.slidingimages_layout, view, false);

            assert imageLayout != null;
            final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) imageLayout
                    .findViewById(R.id.image);

            imageLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                public void onClick(View v){
                    //this will log the page number that was click

                    Log.d("position","position "+position);//not working
                }
            });


            Glide.with(context)
                    .load(urls[position])
                    .into(imageView);

            view.addView(imageLayout, 0);

            return imageLayout;
        }
```